# Strange behaviour when extract url from Google Search Result Page with Javascript

Tags: javascript, console.log

Today I'm interested to try the following interesting piece of Javascript in Chrome:-

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('r')).forEach(x => console.log(x.firstChild.href))
```

As expected, this list out all the target url (without Google tracking) in my console. However when I try to inspect the `href` of the `anchor`, it turns out that the `href` is actually the Google tracking url and the target url (without Google tracking) is in the `data-href` instead.

I expect the value of `href` should be the target url (without Google tracking). May I know what's the cause of this discrepancy?

[image: Google Search Result Page Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I noticed that the anchor inside the Google Search Result Page will trigger an event on mouse click which will change the orignal value of `href` and embed it in `data-href` instead.

That means as long as the anchor doesn't get clicked, the original url of the value of the `href` will be preserved.

My current knowledge doesn't allow me to drill down further and any more detailed or technical explanations are welcome! =)